# Interface Builder: I have several textfields... how do I get the tabs to be correct?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

Using Interface Builder, how do I sequence the tabs so they flow from right to left, top to bottom?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense regarding both text fields and tabs. What kind of tabs do you refer to? The ones on a tab bar controller?

Comment: Sorry... let's say you have 3 textfields, #1,2 and 3 in a row.  I want to be able to go in sequence when filling them in from the k/b, first #1, then #2 and finally #3.  Right to left, top to bottom.

I know about first responders, and this is NOT a first responder issue.  It's got something to do with the tag I think, but that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One basic idea is to implement `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `textFieldShouldReturn:` method, and either

- Check the `textField` object against the outlet properties that you assign to your text fields using IB, or
- Check `textField.tag` against the tags you assign to your text fields using IB or within your view controller's code

Then switch first responders accordingly. You can't tell your view controller the general direction to go and it'll know which text fields to switch (AppKit probably does this through guesswork, but I don't think UIKit does the same), but you can make use of outlets or tags to identify your text fields.